# Outlook Addins can't be clicked unless I select an item/mail

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

[disabled addin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUKOS.png)

When I start the Outlook addin, I can't click this taskpane(?) unless I open an email and then it's not disabled anymore.

Which part of the manifest file should I change to change this behavior? I want it's not disabled even when the user doesn't open/select any email. Because when I change the selected item, it will refresh the page (and I don't want it either).

Thanks!

I tried to change the manifest file from the official site but since I don't quite understand, maybe I misconfigured in some places. I expected this button not disabled even when the user doesn't open/select any email. Because when I change the selected item, it will refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook web add-ins are run under the context of currently selected or opened item in Outlook. Only COM add-ins can be run all the time. The lifetime of mail add-ins is quite different - they are loaded only when  item is selected or opened in an inspector window.

> When I start the Outlook addin, I can't click this taskpane(?) unless I open an email and then it's not disabled anymore.

Ribbon buttons are visible/enabled only for items selected or opened for reasons stated earlier. That is by design. But as a possible workaround you may consider using the events based activation, see [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest) for more information.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Add-ins are contextual to the mail context as it is designed to run on the mail or appointment that is currently open.

Comment: is there something/workaround to achieve what I expected?

Comment: a COM/VSTO addin is probably your only option, but that will only work in the Windows desktop client.

Comment: already have the VSTO version, but we want to develop this version. Turns out it's not possible